# Modulos miss-match of `myserver.key` file during ssl certification on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, web-services

I have accidentally changed the modulus of my  `myserver.key` on the server, is there any way to retrieve my original key file.

Note: initially my ssl was properly integrated.

Comment: if you have changed you key on server and can't access it anymore, than it depends on venders if you can reset access. Are you using ec2?

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal , yes i am using ec2,

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/recover-access-lost-key-pair/ Try this